# Группировка элементов при выводе через each loop в Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, jade

Есть вывод элементов через конструкцию `each` в Jade. Мне нужно обернуть каждые 2 элемента в div-родитель, как это можно реализовать? Я написал следующий код:

```
each  item,i in feature.items
    - if (i.substr(4)%2) {
        .col-group
            .col-mb-8.col-tb-12.col-dt-6
                h4.b--feature__title!=item.title
                p.b--feature__text!=item.text
    - } else {
        .col-mb-8.col-tb-12.col-dt-6
            h4.b--feature__title!=item.title
            p.b--feature__text!=item.text
    - }
```

Но он работает неверно и оборачивает в `.col-group` только первый элемент `.col-mb-8` из двух. Как добавить второй?

Comment: что значит "каждые два"? лично я понимаю так - получили первый, подвесили его в пятом измерение, перешли к следующему. Взяли следующий, создали машину расщепляющую пространство и достали оттуда первый элемент и обернули его... Если это так, то сначала отсортируйте массив объединив по два элемента (при помощи javascript), а уже потом как обычно делайте.